# How do I keep G-Suite Chat signed in?

Tags: google-hangouts

I am looking for any settings that let me keep G-Suite/Hangouts Chat for Windows signed in.

Each time my users open Chat, it asks them to sign in (the button then brings up a browser window that has them input their credentials).

Comment: In what context are you using G-Suite/Hangouts chat?

Answer (score 0):

Google Tech Support helped me solve this for our org. The answer is to change the session length for G-Suite.

**Step 1.** Disable Google Hangouts and Google Hangouts Chat for your org.
**Step 2.** After waiting for a couple minutes, turn them back on.
**Step 3.** [Change G-Suite session length](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7576830?hl=en) to whatever you want it to be. Hangouts and Hangouts Chat will stay signed in for whatever the session length is. (If you choose "indefinite", then it'll always stay signed in, even when you turn on/off your computer.)